# emacs major mode for INF files

Tags: major-mode

Is there a major mode for `.inf` files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INF_file)? If there is one, it's proving to be most unGoogleable.

Comment: You don't like `text-mode`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `conf-windows-mode`.

INF files are essentially `conf-mode` files, so the configuration should work fine.